# How to Meteor package auto install / add / update?

Tags: meteor, package

Is there a way for Meteor to automatically install and/or update a package i.e. if you just add the package name to the .meteor/packages file ?

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail about what you are trying to accomplish? Is this a local package, an atmosphere package, etc.?

Comment: Both Meteor local and Atmosphere package. I realize you can run: meteor update, or mrt update, but that only works if you 1st run the 'add' to add the package. I was wondering if I was missing something so that 'update' would add the package if it was in the packages file  even if it was never added via 'meteor add'.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of local (and core) packages, `meteor add` is the same as appending the package name to `.meteor/packages`. Any updates you make to a local package will automatically be propagated to your app (there is no need to subsequently run an update command).

In the case of atmosphere packages, you must use `mrt add` and `mrt update`. These commands manipulate `smart.json`, `smart.lock`, and the links in the `packages` directory. All of which are necessary for meteor to find and fetch atmosphere packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade versions of all your packages with following command:

```
meteor update
```

Answer (score 0):

To update one or more packages, must be passed the name of the packages to `meteor update package-name` (*replace package-name*) or just run `meteor update --all-packages`.